# Randomly Choose Music From a Folder on my Website

Tags: javascript

I was wondering if there was some way to randomly choose a song and play it when my website loads. The goal is this -

I have a place where users can upload their own songs. The songs are placed in a folder called "music"

I want it to load a random song from that folder. I've searched all over but the only answers were me manually putting the songs in the code. I don't want to do that.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You could use a server-side language to scan the directory for audio files and then return one to the page...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who's wondering:

```html
<?php
$dir = "music/";
$scan = scandir($dir);
$random = rand(2, sizeof($scan)-1);
?>
<html>
<body>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
   music = document.getElementById("music");
   music.volume = 0.2;
   music.play();
  });
</script>


<audio id="music" autoplay >
    <source src="music/<?php echo $scan[$random]; ?>" type="audio/ogg">
</audio>
</body>
</html>
```

This works for me.